# High frequency sounds and hearing damage

Tags: hearing, audiology

First of all, I am not a professional and have only basic everyday understanding of medicine. But this question still is one for medical science:

What frequency range of sounds can damage hearing? Is it only the range that is audible for any given individual, or do near-ultrasonic frequencies also pose a threat?

As a bonus question, is higher frequency sound more dangerous than lower frequency, when at the same amplitude? (Similar to how ionizing high frequency electromagnetic radiation is more dangerous than non-ionizing low frequency one)

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: With light, higher frequency is synonymous with higher energy. That is not the case for sound.